# Do static variables that did not have their address taken need to exist in optimized build executable?

Tags: c++, static

This question came when I was telling people to not use preprocessor, 
for example:

NO:

```
#define SIZE 5;
```

YES:

```
static const size_t SIZE = 5;
```

Then argument was made that variable uses memory, while define is as if you wrote 5 directly in the place you use it.

So my question is(assuming SIZE address is not ever taken, so it is invisible to the rest of the program beside the place where it is used to define array size or for loop iteration count)
Does `static const size_t SIZE` must exist in the memory of the resulting program or are optimizing compilers/linkers allowed to remove it.

Comment: Why make it static? There are no linkage issues with non-static consts.

Comment: This is going to compiler defined but I would assume any decent compiler would optimize it out and use the literal value in its place as long as you don't ODR-use it.

Comment: Optimizing compilers are allowed to do anything that meets the "as-if rule". If the constant's address is never taken, there's no way to tell if it's in memory or not.

Comment: It may or may not use memory, you can't say

Comment: @NeilButterworth convention-IMHO very few people know that const implies static in C++.

Comment: "-IMHO very few people know that const implies static in C++." - possibly because it doesn't? And use of const instead of macros has been the norm since before C++ was standardised - it's one way that Stroustrup tried to get rid of uses of the preprocessor. If people don't know about this kind of use of const I'd suggest the C++ code they write is not worth using. This is very basic C++.

Comment: it does for globals